# Comentário apagado sem motivo

Tags: suporte, comentários, sinalização, moderação

Nesse tópico:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106597/manipulando-escalas-de-cores-com-css-e-php?noredirect=1#comment219361_106597

Uma pegunta fora de escopo, sendo marcada para fechar, fiz um comentário ensinando como buscar no google e ainda apontei um link para um tópico do SO-pt como complemento.

Qual o problema no comentário que fiz? Há "milhares" de comentários desse tipo no site, inclusive muitos desses já fiz várias vezes em outras perguntas. Mas por qual motivo removeu nesse caso?

Pior que remover é deixar o outro comentário do AP que ficou sem sentido.

Parece uma ação arbitrária e sem sentido da parte de quem fez a remoção.

Comment: Já agora a pergunta já foi apagada.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu que apaguei.

O seu primeiro comentário era:

> Para a paleta de cores, digita no google "colors palette css". Para pegar parâmetros no PHP: pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106500

Ele respondeu:

> preciso é do código css para gerar

Portanto esses dois comentários me pareciam desnecessários e eu removi ambos.

Seu segundo comentário era:

> Não é assim que funciona o site. Ninguém aqui fará o seu trabalho. No mínimo você deveria postar algo que já tentou fazer.

Quanto a esse, o autor da pergunta o sinalizou como rude ou ofensivo, ele claramente se sentiu desconfortável com o tom que você usou na sua mensagem. Eu poderia ter editado seu comentário para tentar deixar mais receptivo, entretanto eu acabei optando por apagar por ser mais fácil. Não apaguei o comentário dele pois não tinha certeza que você já tinha lido ou não, mas de qualquer forma agora está apagado.

Comment: ok, Mas não tem nada de rude. Apenas orientei que não é assim que funciona o site. Comentários como esse que postei muitos outros postam até de forma muito mais rude e ofensiva. Eu mesmo já postei isso diversas vezes.. Então por quê apagar esse específico? Quer dizer que qualquer um que pede para remover um comentário, o comentário é removido mesmo sem razão?

Comment: A sua orientação para o usuário está correta, mas pelo menos em minha opinião ele ultrapassa o limite da assertividade e chega ligeiramente no ponto da rudez. Não é qualquer comentário sinalizado que é removido, a moderação pode tanto aceitar como rejeita-las. Se existem outros mais rudes que esses espalhados pelo site o correto seria remover ou editar cada um deles, e não se apoiar neles para criar comentários do gênero.

Comment: @DanielOmine isso de ser com ou sem razão é muito subjetivo. O moderador quando analisa uma sinalização avalia se o comentário trás algo de construtivo à pergunta e se não é "rude" com ninguém. 
Eu não achei o seu comentário ofensivo, mas é verdade que poderia ser mais amistoso. Acho preferível remover um comentário que incomoda e depois, como acontece agora, abrir aqui no meta para debater.

Comment: @JorgeB. poisé, é subjetivo, se não houvesse a sinalização e eu me deparasse com esse comentário por acidente eu provavelmente não o removeria, mas se o AP chegou ao ponto de sinalizá-lo é pq ele claramente se sentiu incomodado, portanto achei melhor remover. Espero que o Daniel não tenha achado minha ação rude :P

Comment: @Math, ok. entendido. Entendo que o intuito maior foi evitar um bate boca desnecessário. Fez o correto. O problema é assim, eu me oriento mais pela ação dos caras que tem maior pontuação. Eu já vi diversas vezes esses mesmos postando coisas desse tipo e até em tom de piada ou mais rude.. Então sempre achei que não tem problema postar isso assim dessa forma.

Comment: Aproveitando, tem algum recurso no qual podemos postar comentário semi-prontos? Por exemplo, poderia ter um menu para casos recorrentes "não poste assim, a pergunta deveria estar dentro do escopo, vejas regras: [link para regras]".. Acho que assim fica menos propenso a postarmos coisas que pareçam rudes ou ofensivas.

Comment: @DanielOmine o melhor é ser sempre simpático e amistoso, claro que isso não é obrigatório, mas aqui como na vida "la fora" o melhor é ser sempre amistoso para toda a gente e tentar ajudar. Não há nada melhor que conseguir ajudar alguém. E mesmo que a pessoa seja rude podes sempre responder com delicadeza, é a chamada "chapada de luva branca" ;)

Comment: @DanielOmine tens aqui um: [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: Conhecia como "bofetada de luva branca".. Acho que ouvi essa expressão em Macau.

Comment: valeu! instalei como plugin do chrome, mas as frases são para o SO-en. Tem como traduzir para português?

Comment: @DanielOmine já tens essas frases também em PT:  [Comentários enlatados para situações comuns](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/coment%C3%A1rios-enlatados-para-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-comuns)

Comment: Comentários são descartáveis, por este motivo concordo contigo, editar não seria um bom caminho.

Comment: Descartável ou não, acho que editar não seria legal porque não tem como reverter, e acho que nem somos notificados disso (dessa edição no coment -  ou somos?). Parece invasivo demais. Acho que se o moderador entende que o post não está adequado, deve apagar e pronto imho. Para passar alguma orientação que estava no post apagado, basta fazer outro, usando um enlatado ou não, vai do ânimo. O que não acho legal é mudar o sentido do que foi dito por um usuário e ele não ter a opção de reverter. E se não for notificado da edição (podendo apagar se quiser), daí seria absurdo mesmo.

Comment: @gustavox não é notificado mesmo. Acho que a edição de comentários é mais usada quando tem muita grosseria mesmo, mas não se quer perder o fio da meada. No geral, o ideal é apesar editar removendo a parte ofensiva e não trocar o sentido do restante do texto, justamente para ficar o menos invasivo possível, mas nesse caso em questão não era nada de absurdo, então como vc bem disse, o ideal aqui é não ficar mexendo nas palavras dos outros.

Comment: Ah, verdade, não tinha mesmo pensado que o comentário pode ser rude/ofensivo e ainda assim conter algo útil para a pergunta/resposta. Neste caso concordo contigo, mas tem que ser **muito** útil hehe, ninguém merece falta de educação e grosseria (e não me refiro ao comment da pergunta, que achei ficar ali no limite mesmo - principalmente pelo recorrente 'Ninguém aqui fará o seu trabalho.' usado a lot por muitos users, e que acho desnecessário). Do contrário, acho que tem que apagar mesmo. No mais, [be nice](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)...

Comment: @gustavox realmente concordo contigo, soa até "invasivo", mas o que eu quis dizer é que em situações necessárias a edição soa mais invasivo que a exclusão. O que acho que falta é uma notificação para o usuário saber o motivo que foi removido.

Comment: Sim @GuilhermeNascimento, concordo absolutamente com a questão da notificação, tanto para exclusão como para edição de comentários. Porque mesmo os comentários sendo descartáveis - e são mesmo imho, porque pelo menos em tese acho que aquilo que for importante no comentário deveria sempre ser incorporado na pergunta/resposta - a notificação serviria até como uma forma de "advertir" o usuário, no sentido de que sua publicação foi considerada inadequada de acordo com os termos do site (de preferência com o termo específico), além da questão do respeito puro e simples, e de evitar eventual abuso.

Answer (score 2):

*"Sem motivo"* não existe.

A remoção de comentários é uma **ação explicita** dos moderadores ou funcionários e normalmente é feita em resposta a sinalizações levantadas por outros usuários.

Inclusive, a sinalização "rude/ofensivo" deleta o comentário se X usuários normais fizerem a mesma sinalização (não lembro qual é o X nem se tem alguma outra sinalização semelhante).

Se é alguma informação importante, *mova pra dentro* da pergunta ou resposta. Comentários são efêmeros e sua importância tende a ZERO com o decorrer do tempo.

Algumas vezes os comentários podem ser importantes, mas outras tantas simplesmente estão atrapalhando a leitura da Pergunta e Respostas, e é por isso que podemos pedir sua remoção como:

[image]